# how to set data A to Z alphabetic order when user select A to Z into drop down in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, css, react-native

I'm creating a screen that can be displayed 1000 data it comes from the API

here is image

[image]

now I have a drop-down box where users select A to Z alphabet into a drop-down box then after selecting A to Z alphabetic order then  data arange in A to Z alphabetic order. all data set in A to Z order so how can I do this function in my code

I'm try this code

```
 // setData(json.results);  <==================it for sorting
      // setData((prevData) => [...prevData, ...newData]);

      // const sorted = [...sortedData, ...newData].sort((a, b) => {
      //   const lastNameA = a.name.first.toLowerCase();
      //   const lastNameB = b.name.first.toLowerCase();
      //   if (lastNameA < lastNameB) return -1;
      //   if (lastNameA > lastNameB) return 1;
      //   return 0;
      // });
      // setSortedData(sorted);
```

but its not working when I'm selecting A to Z order list in to drop down box

how can I do that ?

**code:**

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
  SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-native';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { scale, verticalScale, moderateScale } from 'react-native-size-matters';
import { RFPercentage } from 'react-native-responsive-fontsize';
import SelectDropdown from 'react-native-select-dropdown';

const sortby = ['A to Z', 'Newawst', 'Oldest'];

const App = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [filteredDataSource, setFilteredDataSource] = useState([]);
  const [masterDataSource, setMasterDataSource] = useState([]);
  const [total, setTotalData] = useState(0);
  const [searchCount, setSearchCount] = useState(0);
  const [sortedData, setSortedData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api?results=1000');
      const json = await response.json();
      const newData = json.results;

      setLoading(false);
      setFilteredDataSource(json.results);
      setMasterDataSource(json.results);
      setTotalData(json.info.results);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const searchFilterFunction = (text) => {
    // Check if searched text is not blank
    if (text) {
      // Inserted text is not blank
      // Filter the masterDataSource and update FilteredDataSource
      const newData = masterDataSource.filter(function (item) {
        // Applying filter for the inserted text in search bar
        const itemData = item.name.first
          ? item.name.first.toUpperCase()
          : ''.toUpperCase();
        const textData = text.toUpperCase();
        return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
      });
      setFilteredDataSource(newData);
      setSearch(text);
      setSearchCount(newData.length);
    } else {
      // Inserted text is blank
      // Update FilteredDataSource with masterDataSource
      setFilteredDataSource(masterDataSource);
      setSearch(text);
    }
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
      <Text>Name :{`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}</Text>
      <Text>Email :{item.email}</Text>
      <Text>City :{item.location.city}</Text>
      <Text>State :{item.location.state}</Text>
      <Text>Country :{item.location.country}</Text>
      <Text>Postcode :{item.location.postcode}</Text>
    </View>
  );
  const ItemSeparatorView = () => {
    return (
      // Flat List Item Separator
      <View
        style={{
          height: 0.5,
          width: '100%',
          backgroundColor: '#000',
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Image source={require('../img/menu.png')} style={styles.menuimg} />
        <Image source={require('../img/logo.png')} style={styles.logoimg} />
        <Image source={require('../img/user.png')} style={styles.userimg} />
      </View>
      <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <View style={styles.textbox}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.textInputStyle}
            onChangeText={(text) => searchFilterFunction(text)}
            value={search}
            focusable={true}
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            placeholder="Search"
            placeholderTextColor={'#000'}
            selectionColor="#000"
          />
          <Image
            source={require('../img/filter.png')}
            style={{ marginRight: scale(10) }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          marginTop: verticalScale(10),
          justifyContent: 'space-around',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <Text style={styles.resulttext}>
          {searchCount == 0 ? total : searchCount} results
        </Text>
        <SelectDropdown
          data={sortby}
          // defaultValueByIndex={1}
          onSelect={(selectedItem, index) => {
            console.log(selectedItem, index);
          }}
          defaultButtonText={'Sort By'}
          buttonTextAfterSelection={(selectedItem, index) => {
            return selectedItem;
          }}
          rowTextForSelection={(item, index) => {
            return item;
          }}
          buttonStyle={styles.dropdown2BtnStyle}
          buttonTextStyle={styles.dropdown2BtnTxtStyle}
          renderDropdownIcon={(isOpened) => {
            return isOpened ? (
              <>
                <Image
                  source={require('../img/arrowup.png')}
                  style={{
                    width: scale(15),
                    height: verticalScale(15),
                    marginRight: verticalScale(10),
                  }}
                />
              </>
            ) : (
              <>
                <Image
                  source={require('../img/arrowdown.png')}
                  style={{
                    width: scale(15),
                    height: verticalScale(15),
                    marginRight: verticalScale(10),
                  }}
                />
              </>
            );
          }}
          dropdownIconPosition={'right'}
          dropdownStyle={styles.dropdown2DropdownStyle}
          rowStyle={styles.dropdown2RowStyle}
          rowTextStyle={styles.dropdown2RowTxtStyle}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={{ marginTop: scale(10) }}>
        <SafeAreaView>
          {loading ? (
            <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="black" />
          ) : (
            <FlatList
              data={filteredDataSource}
              renderItem={renderItem}
              ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparatorView}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            />
          )}
        </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  contenir: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  header: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginLeft: verticalScale(10),
    marginRight: verticalScale(10),
  },
  menuimg: { width: scale(40), height: verticalScale(40) },
  logoimg: {
    width: scale(60),
    height: verticalScale(60),
    marginTop: scale(10),
  },
  userimg: {
    width: scale(60),
    height: verticalScale(60),
    marginTop: scale(10),
  },
  textInputStyle: {
    // height: verticalScale(60),
    width: scale(260),
    fontSize: RFPercentage(3),
    color: '#000',
    fontWeight: '900',
    // borderWidth: scale(2),
    // paddingLeft:moderateScale(20),
    // margin: scale(5),
    // borderRadius:scale(20),
    // borderColor: '#000',
    // backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  },
  textbox: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: verticalScale(65),
    width: scale(320),
    borderColor: '#000',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderRadius: scale(30),
    borderWidth: scale(2),
    paddingLeft: moderateScale(20),
    margin: scale(5),
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  resulttext: {
    fontSize: RFPercentage(3.7),
    fontWeight: '700',
    color: '#000',
    // marginLeft: scale(20)
  },
  // scrollViewContainer: {
  //     justifyContent: 'space-around',
  // },
  dropdown2BtnStyle: {
    width: scale(150),
    height: verticalScale(60),
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    borderRadius: scale(30),
  },
  dropdown2BtnTxtStyle: {
    color: '#FFF',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: RFPercentage(2.5),
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  dropdown2DropdownStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#444',
    width: scale(120),
    height: verticalScale(70),
    borderRadius: scale(20),
    // borderBottomRightRadius: 12,
  },
  dropdown2RowStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#000',
  },
  dropdown2RowTxtStyle: {
    color: '#FFF',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. It worked for me.

```
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Image,
    TextInput,
    FlatList,
    ActivityIndicator,
    SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-native';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { scale, verticalScale, moderateScale } from 'react-native-size-matters';
import { RFPercentage } from 'react-native-responsive-fontsize';
import SelectDropdown from 'react-native-select-dropdown';

const sortby = ['A to Z', 'Newawst', 'Oldest'];

const App = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
    const [filteredDataSource, setFilteredDataSource] = useState([]);
    const [masterDataSource, setMasterDataSource] = useState([]);
    const [total, setTotalData] = useState(0);
    const [searchCount, setSearchCount] = useState(0);
    const [sortedData, setSortedData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api?results=1000');
            const json = await response.json();
            const newData = json.results;

            setLoading(false);
            setFilteredDataSource(json.results);
            setMasterDataSource(json.results);
            setTotalData(json.info.results);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };

    const searchFilterFunction = (text) => {
        // Check if searched text is not blank
        if (text) {
            // Inserted text is not blank
            // Filter the masterDataSource and update FilteredDataSource
            const newData = masterDataSource.filter(function (item) {
                // Applying filter for the inserted text in search bar
                const itemData = item.name.first
                    ? item.name.first.toUpperCase()
                    : ''.toUpperCase();
                const textData = text.toUpperCase();
                return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
            });
            setFilteredDataSource(newData);
            setSearch(text);
            setSearchCount(newData.length);
        } else {
            // Inserted text is blank
            // Update FilteredDataSource with masterDataSource
            setFilteredDataSource(masterDataSource);
            setSearch(text);
        }
    };

    const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
            <Text>Name :{`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}</Text>
            <Text>Email :{item.email}</Text>
            <Text>City :{item.location.city}</Text>
            <Text>State :{item.location.state}</Text>
            <Text>Country :{item.location.country}</Text>
            <Text>Postcode :{item.location.postcode}</Text>
        </View>
    );
    const ItemSeparatorView = () => {
        return (
            // Flat List Item Separator
            <View
                style={{
                    height: 0.5,
                    width: '100%',
                    backgroundColor: '#000',
                }}
            />
        );
    };

    return (
        <View>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Image source={require('../assets/google.png')} style={styles.menuimg} />
                <Image source={require('../assets/google.png')} style={styles.logoimg} />
                <Image source={require('../assets/google.png')} style={styles.userimg} />
            </View>
            <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <View style={styles.textbox}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.textInputStyle}
                        onChangeText={(text) => searchFilterFunction(text)}
                        value={search}
                        focusable={true}
                        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                        placeholder="Search"
                        placeholderTextColor={'#000'}
                        selectionColor="#000"
                    />
                    <Image
                        source={require('../assets/google.png')}
                        style={{ marginRight: scale(10) }}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
            <View
                style={{
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    marginTop: verticalScale(10),
                    justifyContent: 'space-around',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                }}>
                <Text style={styles.resulttext}>
                    {searchCount == 0 ? total : searchCount} results
                </Text>
                <SelectDropdown
                    data={sortby}
                    // defaultValueByIndex={1}
                    onSelect={(selectedItem, index) => {
                        console.log(selectedItem, index);
                        //check here
                        if (selectedItem == 'A to Z') {
                            const filterThisArray = [...filteredDataSource];
                            filterThisArray.sort((a, b) => {
                                const nameA = a.name.first.toLowerCase();
                                const nameB = b.name.first.toLowerCase();

                                if (nameA < nameB) {
                                    return -1;
                                }
                                if (nameA > nameB) {
                                    return 1;
                                }
                                return 0;
                            });
                            setFilteredDataSource(filterThisArray);
                        }
                    }}
                    defaultButtonText={'Sort By'}
                    buttonTextAfterSelection={(selectedItem, index) => {
                        return selectedItem;
                    }}
                    rowTextForSelection={(item, index) => {
                        return item;
                    }}
                    buttonStyle={styles.dropdown2BtnStyle}
                    buttonTextStyle={styles.dropdown2BtnTxtStyle}
                    renderDropdownIcon={(isOpened) => {
                        return isOpened ? (
                            <>
                                <Image
                                    source={require('../assets/google.png')}
                                    style={{
                                        width: scale(15),
                                        height: verticalScale(15),
                                        marginRight: verticalScale(10),
                                    }}
                                />
                            </>
                        ) : (
                            <>
                                <Image
                                    source={require('../assets/google.png')}
                                    style={{
                                        width: scale(15),
                                        height: verticalScale(15),
                                        marginRight: verticalScale(10),
                                    }}
                                />
                            </>
                        );
                    }}
                    dropdownIconPosition={'right'}
                    dropdownStyle={styles.dropdown2DropdownStyle}
                    rowStyle={styles.dropdown2RowStyle}
                    rowTextStyle={styles.dropdown2RowTxtStyle}
                />
            </View>

            <View style={{ marginTop: scale(10) }}>
                <SafeAreaView>
                    {loading ? (
                        <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="black" />
                    ) : (
                        <FlatList
                            data={filteredDataSource}
                            renderItem={renderItem}
                            ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparatorView}
                            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                        />
                    )}
                </SafeAreaView>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    contenir: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    header: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginLeft: verticalScale(10),
        marginRight: verticalScale(10),
    },
    menuimg: { width: scale(40), height: verticalScale(40) },
    logoimg: {
        width: scale(60),
        height: verticalScale(60),
        marginTop: scale(10),
    },
    userimg: {
        width: scale(60),
        height: verticalScale(60),
        marginTop: scale(10),
    },
    textInputStyle: {
        // height: verticalScale(60),
        width: scale(260),
        fontSize: RFPercentage(3),
        color: '#000',
        fontWeight: '900',
        // borderWidth: scale(2),
        // paddingLeft:moderateScale(20),
        // margin: scale(5),
        // borderRadius:scale(20),
        // borderColor: '#000',
        // backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    },
    textbox: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: verticalScale(65),
        width: scale(320),
        borderColor: '#000',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        borderRadius: scale(30),
        borderWidth: scale(2),
        paddingLeft: moderateScale(20),
        margin: scale(5),
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
    resulttext: {
        fontSize: RFPercentage(3.7),
        fontWeight: '700',
        color: '#000',
        // marginLeft: scale(20)
    },
    // scrollViewContainer: {
    //     justifyContent: 'space-around',
    // },
    dropdown2BtnStyle: {
        width: scale(150),
        height: verticalScale(60),
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        borderRadius: scale(30),
    },
    dropdown2BtnTxtStyle: {
        color: '#FFF',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: RFPercentage(2.5),
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    dropdown2DropdownStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#444',
        width: scale(120),
        height: verticalScale(70),
        borderRadius: scale(20),
        // borderBottomRightRadius: 12,
    },
    dropdown2RowStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#000',
    },
    dropdown2RowTxtStyle: {
        color: '#FFF',
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
});
```

Don't forget to handle other options as well ;)